# How to restart a service when the CPU usage is over N%?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, resources, ubuntu-18.04

I have a website hosted on a server (ubuntu 18.04) with 2 core CPU and 4GB RAM. My website usually has 200 concurrent sessions in real-time (online users) on average.

Also, for those 200 online users, the resources usage will be almost:

- 50% of the RAM
- 65% of the CPU

---

It should be noted, my website is a Q/A website. So, users come to my website and ask their questions in different fields. Sometimes in a TV contest, a question asks and people immediately come to my website to search about it. Or they search inside google and find the link of my website and they invade my website.

In that case, **the CPU of my server will be used over 90%** and it's mostly because of the MySQL service.

Also, there is another scenario. When the google-bot crawler starts indexing my websites' links or checks for broken links, again, the same CPU usage happens. The point is, I cannot increase the server resources at the moment. I will do that in the future when I got a sponsor for my website.

So, as a workaround, I'm just trying to write a script that restarts the MySQL service automatically when the CPU usage is over 90%. Currently, I do that manually when I see my website is down or there's a page loading delay.

---

After some researches, I could get the real-time CPU usage percentage by this command:

```
echo $[100-$(vmstat 1 2|tail -1|awk '{print $15}')]
```

Also, I restart MySQL this way:

```
systemctl restart mysql
```

---

My exact question is, how can I exactly write that condition as a Linux bash script?

```
#!/bin/bash

if <how to check CPU usage> then
   systemctl restart mysql
fi
```

Comment: Maybe unrelated: With limited bandwidth, perhaps a simple remedy as installing the `bm` (bandwidth) module and configuring it that appropriately would do. I did that when having an ADSL line and got "some usage". It helped a lot. I still use the same module but just increase the max load whenever I upgrade to a better connection. It was really easy to configure too. Works like a charm.

Comment: Why do you think restarting mysql could help? You are just postponing the problem. Fix the root cause, if there's something wrong with MySQL, limit the number of connections, cpu, etc.

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano You are right, the root cause must be solved in such situations. But the root of my question is weak server resources for being compatible with over 200 concurrent users. The sad part is we can not upgrade the server. That's why I'm just trying to heal a little bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to go this route, just check whether the usage is over 90%. Then run this script periodically using `cron`.

```
#! /bin/bash
(( usage = 100 - $(vmstat 1 2 | tail -n1 | awk '{print $15}') ))
if (( usage > 90 )); then
  systemctl restart mysql
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, assuming the bash scrip file is located `/var/www/bash/restart_mysql.sh`, then the cron should be like this? `* * * * * /var/www/bash/restart_mysql.sh`

Comment: Yes, if you want to check your CPU usage every minute, then that seems fine. Otherwise you could use `*/5 * * * * /var/www/...` to check the CPU usage only every five minutes.

Comment: I get an error: usage not found

Comment: @Roman sounds like you are using a different shell than bash. Inside `(( ))` bash interprets `usage` as a variable, but in your case it seems to be interpreted as a command, which does not exist. But the error message for missing commands in bash looks different too, so I am pretty sue you are using a different shell.